# double integral over oriented closed surface

Tags: symbols

Is there a command, presumably in the esint package, to create a double integral symbol similar to the one created by `\oiint`, but with an arrow indicating whether the surface is oriented outward or inward?

The arrow should be pointing inside or outside the little closed loop, not a clockwise or counterclockwise arrow.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\newcommand\inoiint{\to\kern-1.8ex\oiint}
    \begin{document}
\[ \inoiint x\,dx\ y\,dy  \] 
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is not quite what I want.  I want the arrows to indicate outward or inward orientation, not clockwise or counterclockwise.  Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @Rohan, it seems that you looking for new symbol (not known to me). Can you provide some sketch of it?

Comment: Something like $\leftarrow\oiint$.

Comment: Like this: `\newcommand\inoiint{\to\kern-2ex\oiint}`? and than `\[ \inoiint x\,dx\ y\,dy \]`? With package `txfonts` or `esint` ... Rude solution, but  on waiting on better solution it can serve :-).

Comment: @Rohan, than I will upgrade my answer ...